# I want to write a code that can search in columns with just few letters from the cell

Tags: python-2.7, sqlite

I created a table contains columns (name , address) I want to write a code make a loop into rows and search for all names contains (a,s) , I do that

```
Cur.execute('SELECT names FROM members')
for row in cur:
    if (names contain e,s "the missing code")
    print row
```

Comment: I guess you do not want to search for the five-letter string "`(a,s)`" but for the two characters? Both or only one?

Comment: If it possible i want the user who determinate the letters for searching

    Cur.execute('SELECT names FROM members')
    for row in cur:
        search = raw_input(" Enter any letters of names you want to 
        search here ")
        if (names contain search "the missing code")
    print row

Comment: This does not answer my question. Are some or all letters required to match?

Answer (score 0):

If it possible i want the user who determinate the letters for searching

```
Cur.execute('SELECT names FROM members')
for row in cur:
    search = raw_input(" Enter any letters of names you want to 
    search here ")
    if (names contain search "the missing code")
print row
```